# Using EasyUploads add-on

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I'm new of vaadin and this is the first time that i use an add-on [EasyUpload](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/easyuploads)

```
MultiFileUpload multiFileUpload2 = new MultiFileUpload() {
        @Override
        protected void handleFile(File file, String fileName,
                String mimeType, long length) {
            String msg = fileName + " uploaded. Saved to file "
                    + file.getAbsolutePath() + " (size " + length
                    + " bytes)";

            mainWindow.showNotification(msg);
        }

        @Override
        protected FileBuffer createReceiver() {
            FileBuffer receiver = super.createReceiver();
            /*
             * Make receiver not to delete files after they have been
             * handled by #handleFile().
             */
            receiver.setDeleteFiles(false);
            return receiver;
        }
    };
```

Now I'm getting an trouble when try to upload two time a file with the same name.
Precisely i have a file "test.txt", using the button "choose files" I select this file on my pc and I do the upload. If I want to redo the upload the same file the component doesn't work, I try to put a few breakpoint on

> handleFile() and createReceiver()

but these are not considered, while if I change file everything works.
How can I do to fix this trouble?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Do you receive a error, a stack trace, light goes out, or what? Of course you must descide what to do with the files received and how to handle duplicate file names...

Comment: The component seem not respond anymore, I'm not able not even to intercept a break point (Google Chrome Version 33.0.1750.154), while with firefox  28.0 everything works

Comment: Perhaps it's a Chrome 33 bug? Have you tested with IE?

Comment: I tried the component in IE and it seems that it works, but  this browser doesn't show the dropzone area of the component

Comment: So for me it looks like a problem of the component with Chrome 33. It's normal that IE has no drop zone) Isuggest contacting the author of the component...

Comment: Why is normal that IE doesn't have a drop zone?

Comment: https://vaadin.com/de/directory#addon/multifileupload

Supported HTML5 capable browsers for multiple upload: Firefox, Chrome, Safari Supported browsers for single upload: all

IE is always 2-3 versions behind in functionality...